# How to test ARKit app using ARGeoTrackingConfig in unsupported area?

Tags: swift, mapkit, arkit, realitykit

I have downloaded and installed this [project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/tracking_geographic_locations_in_ar) from Apple ARKit documentation and when opening it says GeoLocation tracking is unsupported in this area. I have gone through the details and in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/argeotrackingconfiguration) India is not listed in supported countries or areas.

I want to try [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/recording_and_replaying_ar_session_data) method to test my app, and for that need a recorded session from the Reality Composer app. I searched over the internet to download a test session video but was not able to find it. If anyone can provide a solution for this.

Comment: Please help to fix this

Comment: Read this post, please. – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800039/realitykit-adding-modelentity-to-an-argeoanchor/71801799#71801799